# receive windows popup message or alert for a specific incoming mail

Tags: powershell, outlook

we have following problem. we need an extra windows popup message or baloon tip message in windows, if a mail from a specific sender arrives in outlook. are there any examples in powershell or any other programms recommend?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic Outlook rules to create a desktop alert with any given condition, no need for any script or special program

If you want, the rule can also run a script and then you can do whatever you want there

Comment: how can i add a custom script for receiving mail in outlook rules? can't find it

Comment: @chkdsk see [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)

Comment: i add a fix to the registry to get the "run as script" showing up. i added the following code from https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/ to the vba editor but in my rules the script list ist empty

Answer (score 0):

From the following webpage, https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

Using VBA

Something like this:

```
Public Sub ShowMessage(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

'code

End Sub
```

The argument must by type MailItem or MeetingItem for the subroutine to be available in the Rules Wizard in Outlook 2007. In Outlook 2010 and 2013 (and up), PostItem also works.

Open Rules Wizard. In Outlook 2010 and 2013, it's on Outlook's Home ribbon,
Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts. Look on the Tools menu in older versions.
Open Rules Wizard
Click New Rule.
Select Apply Rule on messages I receive and click Next.
Select your conditions and click Next.
Select Run a script action (near the bottom).
The finished run a script rule
Click on a script.
Select the script
Select your script, click OK.
Click Next then finish the rule.

Comment: i add a fix to the registry to get the "run as script" showing up. i added the following code from https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/ to the vba editor but in my rules the script list ist empty

Comment: With the code you copied, and then using the link i put into my answer, did you follow this? Which version or Outlook are you using?

Comment: yes i did it but what i already said, my script list is empty. maybe the code in the vba editor is wrong?

Comment: Please check that the argument must be by type MailItem or MeetingItem for the subroutine to be available in the Rules Wizard in Outlook 2007. In Outlook 2010 and 2013 (and up), PostItem also works

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the job done:

1. Create a rule in Outlook manually and assign a VBA macro which can be triggered by the rule. For example:

```
Public Sub TestRule(Item As Object)

If(Item.SenderEmailAddress = "eugene@test.com") Then
 MsgBox "Got email!"
End If

End Sub
```

2. Use the VBA routine for handling incoming emails. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
   Dim mai as Object
   Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)

   If(mai.SenderEmailAddress = "eugene@test.com") Then
     MsgBox "Got email!"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added your second code to VBA editor. After that i just wanted to create a rule and add my custom script but the script list is empty

Comment: The second solution doesn't require additional rule set up in Outlook. You need to go to the VBA editor in Outlook and select the `Application` on the left-hand side combobox  as the events source, then on the right hand-side you will be able to choose the `NewMailEx` event by selecting which the corresponding event handler will be added.